# Registering Android deep link path without including subdomains

Tags: android

I am trying to create a deep link to match a URL specifically on the specified domain, and not on any subdomains. My intent filter `<data />` entry looks like this:

```
<data
  android:host="example.com"
  android:pathPrefix="/somepath"
  android:scheme="https" />
```

This works fine, and matches URLs with `https://example.com/somepath` as I'd expect. However, there are also URLs that I have that look like `https://subdomain.example.com/somepath` that I do not want to match. These are picked up by that data entry as well!

I want to match STRICTLY on the host and not include any subdomains. Is this possible in Android?

It's not possible to change the URL scheme for either set of links.

Answer (score 0):

As I see in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element), your configuration will not match with subdomains.

If you want to accept all subdomains you have to use an asterisk (`*`) character before your host like this: `*.example.com`.

So, the answer is: `example.com` will not match with any subdomains like `subdomain.example.com`

I have created and Activity with the following intent-filter

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <data
       android:host="example.com"
       android:pathPrefix="/somepath"
       android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

This opens test.example.com in a browser window:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://test.example.com/somepath/test"
```

This opens my application:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://example.com/somepath/test"
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have the opposite problem - I do not want to match subdomains, so I have left out any wildcards, and it is matching the subdomain anyway.

Comment: I have created a test project and it works fine for me.

Comment: I have update my answer with the inter-filter, which worked for me.

Comment: I think what the author was asking was support for both domain and subdomain.

Comment: I think the author do not wanted to include subdomains: "I want to match STRICTLY on the host and not include any subdomains."

However now I think the android:autoVerify attribute also can be used for this.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks